How do we approach this type of a question
This is the question I was finding really hard and lengthy to solve
This came as a comprehension in one of my test papers.
In fact, I used Euler substitution here: the denominator in the I was taken as $t$, then $\mathrm dt$ and all I did but couldn't evaluate it...
Consider the following integrals
$$
I=\int_1^2 \frac{1}{x-1+\sqrt{x^2-3 x+3}} dx \text { and } J=\int_1^2 \frac{x^2-x+1}{x(2 x-1)^2} d x
$$
Answer the following questions:
Q.(21) The value of $I-2 J$ is equal to
Q.(22) The value of sgn$(4(I-J)-1)+8+\operatorname{sgn}(2-4(I-J))$ is equal to

Perhaps J could be solved using partial fraction decomposition. You might find this example helpful.

Please make the title more informative and specific.

In particular, ANN, the title should tell us something about the mathematics, not something about you.

You have had three answers, ANN, and we haven't heard a peep from you about any of them. And you haven't improved the title. This is not the way to acknowledge the people who are trying to help you.

I will just answer Q.(21):
For J: The denominator of this expression is a product of linear factors, so it's suitable for us to apply the following technique:

Integration of Rational Functions by Partial Fractions:
There exists constant $A_{1},A_{2},\cdots, A_{k}$ such that
$$
\frac{R(x)}{Q(x)} = \frac{A_{1}}{a_{1}x+b_{1}} + \frac{A_{2}}{a_{2}x+b_{2}} + \cdots + \frac{A_{k}}{a_{k}x+b_{k}} 
$$

First, we perform the partial fraction decomposition:
$$
\frac{x^2-x+1}{x(2x-1)^2} = \frac{A}{x} + \frac{B}{2x-1} + \frac{C}{(2x-1)^2}
$$
Then simplify the right side of this equation, we get:
$$
\frac{(4A+2B)x^2 + (−4A−B+C)x + A}{x(2x-1)^2}
$$
Compare the coefficients of the numerators:
$$
\begin{cases}
4A + 2B = 1 \\
-4A - B + C = -1 \\
A = 1
\end{cases}
$$
Solve these equations by back substitution:
$$
\begin{cases}
A = 1 \\
B = -\frac{3}{2} \\
C = \frac{3}{2}
\end{cases}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\int_{1}^{2} \frac{x^2-x+1}{x(2x-1)^2} dx = \int_{1}^{2} (\frac{1}{x} - \frac{\frac{3}{2}}{2x-1} + \frac{\frac{3}{2}}{(2x-1)^2}) dx = \left[ \ln|x|- \frac{3}{4}\ln|2x-1| - \frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{2x-1}\right]_{1}^{2}
$$
$$
J = \ln2 - \frac{3}{4}\ln3 + \frac{1}{2}
$$
For I:
First, use Euler substitution, letting $u = \sqrt{x^2-3x+3}+x$ (I did not include 1 here because I aim to construct linear factors in the denominator), therefore $x = \frac{u^2-3}{2u-3}$, and $dx = \frac{2(u^2-3u+3)}{(2u-3)^2}du$
$$
\int_{1}^{2}\frac{1}{x-1+\sqrt{x^2-3x+3}}dx = \int_{2}^{3}\frac{2(u^2-3u+3)}{(u-1)(2u-3)^2} du
$$
You can then solve for $I$ using partial fraction decomposition, similar to how we solved for $J$ above.

If in your last formula you now make the change of variables $v=u-1$ you get something very reminiscent of J.

@GerryMyerson You're absolutely right! That's amazing. Thanks for pointing that out :D

If you want to avoid the tediousness of doing PFD, you can proceed as follows:
$\textbf{For I:}$
$$I=\int_1^2 \frac{\mathrm dx}{x-1+\sqrt{x^2-3 x+3}}$$
One possible way to proceed forward is to rationalize the denominator. In doing so, there would only be a linear term in the denominator, and it would be easy to deal with if it did not contain any constant.
$$\not{x^2}-3x+3-\not{x^2}+2x-1=2-x$$
Hence, it would be feasible to do the substitution $2-x=t$:
$$I=\int_0^1\frac{\sqrt{t^2-t+1}+t-1}{t}\mathrm dt$$
$$=\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\sqrt{t^2-t+1}-1}{t}\mathrm dt}_{I_1}+\int_0^1\mathrm dt$$
Note that $I_1$ has been chosen this way since it exists. If we assume $\int_0^1\frac{\sqrt{t^2-t+1}}{t}\mathrm dt$ as $I_1$ instead, it and $\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm dt}{t}$ would be divergent improper integrals.
To evaluate $I_1$, rationalize the square root:
$$I_1=\int_0^1\frac{\frac12\left(2t-1\right)-\frac12}{\sqrt{t^2-t+1}}\mathrm dt+\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm dt}{t^2}\cdot\left(\frac1{\sqrt{\frac1{t^2}-\frac1{t}+1}}-\frac1{\frac1{t}}\right)$$
You can take it from here.
$\textbf{For J:}$
$$J=\int_1^2 \frac{x^2-x+1}{x(2 x-1)^2} \mathrm dx$$
$$=\frac14\int_1^2 \frac{\left(x-\frac12\right)^2+\frac34}{x\left(x-\frac12\right)^2} \mathrm dx$$
$$=\frac14\int_1^2\frac{\mathrm dx}{x}+\frac3{16}\underbrace{\int_1^2\frac{\mathrm dx}{x\left(x-\frac12\right)^2}}_{J_1}$$
To evaluate $J_1$, substitute $x-\frac12=\frac1{t}$:
$$J_1=\int_{\frac23}^2\frac{\mathrm dt}{\frac1{t}+\frac12}$$
$$=2\int_{\frac23}^2\frac{t\mathrm dt}{t+2}$$

Notice that the bounds of $I$ and $J$ are the same. This gives a hint to make the integrands similar. Indeed, this can be done as per @Gerry Myerson's comment by doing Euler's substitution(which you tried) in $I$:
$$t = \sqrt{x^2-3x+3}+x-1$$
$$\implies t^2-2t(x-1)+x^2-2x+1=x^2-3x+3$$
$$\implies x=\frac{t^2+2t-2}{2t-1}$$
$$\implies \mathrm dx=\frac{(2t+2)(2t-1)-2(t^2+2t-2)}{(2t-1)^2}\mathrm dt$$
$$\implies \mathrm dx=2\cdot\frac{t^2-t+1}{(2t-1)^2}\mathrm dt$$
$$\implies I=2\int_1^2\frac{t^2-t+1}{t(2t-1)^2}\mathrm dt=2J$$
Now, you can evaluate $J$ as per my previous answer.
